# Wordpress: add html code to every third post in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap I coded my loop as 3 columns grid layout:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
       //The content
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
       //The content
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
       //The content
      </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Now I need to include every 3 columns between `.row` div:

```
<div class="row">
//loop of each three posts
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you add the row div tag inside the loop around the 3 columns then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to close each row, since you're using Bootstrap:

> If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.

As a result, you don't even need to add a counter:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) :
    echo '<div class="row">';
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            //The content
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; 
    echo '</div>'
?>
```

However, if (for some reason) you actually *do* need rows, add a simple counter:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) :
    $i = 1;
    echo '<div class="row">';
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            //The content
        </div>
    <?php 
    if ( $i % 3 === 0 ) { echo '</div><div class="row">'; }
    $i++; 
    endwhile; 
    echo '</div>'
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this .

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : 
    echo '<div class="row">';
    $i=0; 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    $i++; 
    if($i%3==0)
    echo '</div><div class="row">';
    ?>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
           //The content
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
           //The content
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
           //The content
          </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Just as an explanation of %, the magical modulus: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: The output gave 2 cols for the first row and 3 cols for every next rows. I changed to if($i%4==0) to make it work.